# How to detect a modifier key-combination upon button click in java

Tags: java, swing, click, modifier

I have a button in a Java Swing application for zooming to a selection.  I implemented 3 ways of clicking it:

- click: zooms to selection with a step-wise animation
- option-click: does a single zoom step toward the selection
- command-click: zooms suddenly to full selection

I would like to implement the reverse behaviors (i.e. zoom *from* the selection outward to full zoom-out) when additionally, the shift key is held, so it would be like this:

- shift-click: zooms out fully with a step-wise animation
- shift-option-click: does a single zoom step away from the selection
- shift-command-click: zooms suddenly to full zoom-out

I know how to do everything except the shift-option-click and shift-command-click.  E.g. Here's how I do the single step zoom-in:

```
int stepMask = InputEvent.ALT_MASK;
if((e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.ALT_MASK) == stepMask) {
    //do the single-step zoom
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do a key-combination with a click.  Everything I've tried only works with a single modifier key.  How do I detect a key-combo upon a button-click?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The modifiers value is a bitwise-or'd value containing all the InputEvent modifiers related to the event. To identify particular modifiers, check all you deem necessary for the given logic:

```
if((e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.ALT_MASK) != 0 && (e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0 ) {
    //code for event
}
```

Comment: Why not simplify that to 
if((e.getModifiers() & (InputEvent.ALT_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0 ) {
    //code for event
}

Comment: @Gordon because that code would execute if either alt _or_ shift were being held down.

Comment: No it wouldn't. It's a mask.

Answer (score 0):

There's a more graceful approach. First, define your combined mask as a constant:

```
private static final int SHIFT_OPTION_MASK = InputEvent.ALT_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK;
```

Then, in the button's ActionListener, do this:

```
if((e.getModifiers() & SHIFT_OPTION_MASK) == SHIFT_OPTION_MASK) {
    // code for event
}
```

If you have a lot of these, you could go a step further. Start by defining an enum:

```
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public enum ModifierKey {
    ALT(InputEvent.ALT_MASK),
    SHIFT(InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK),
    CONTROL(InputEvent.CTRL_MASK),
    COMMAND(InputEvent.META_MASK);
    // add more enum values here as needed

    public static boolean checkFor(ActionEvent e, ModifierKey... expectedModifiers) {
        int expectedModifierMask = 0;
        for (ModifierKey expectedModifier : expectedModifiers) {
            expectedModifierMask |= expectedModifier.getMask();
        }
        return (e.getModifiers() & expectedModifierMask) == expectedModifierMask;
    }

    private final int mask;

    ModifierKey(int mask) {
        this.mask = mask;
    }

    public int getMask() {
        return mask;
    }
}
```

Then, in your actionListener, you get to do this instead:

```
import static ModifierKey.*;

...

if (checkFor(e, OPTION, SHIFT)) {
    // code for event
}
```

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter, would you care to comment? I'm using this in practice. It works perfectly, and IMO is much more readable.

Comment: 20+ lines and code that uses a custom method in every event that somebody else touching the code has to remember to use or look up when they first see it, compared to the one-line `if((e.getModifiers() & (InputEvent.ALT_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0 )` which is perfectly readable itself? It's not like the InputEvent constants are confusingly named. How is your version "much more readable"? It looks like boilerplate for the sake of boilerplate to me.

Comment: You're more than welcome to that opinion. :) In my relatively large Swing app, I'm using the checkFor function in dozens of places (note that in my answer I wrote "if you have a lot of these." I find each of them to be more readable, and easier to get the syntax right, so the extra twenty lines (which I never have to touch) pay for themselves easily.

Comment: Furthermore, each call to checkFor is several characters shorter than the equivalent "raw" approach, not to mention that it doesn't include any bitwise manipulation, which I find to be error prone. Having spent ten minutes writing those twenty lines, I save thirty seconds every time I need to check for modifier keys.